# Create a regex for a string with 1 item that changes

Tags: css, regex

I am trying to build a **regex** for an inline CSS code that 1 item on changes

This is the line of code in question

```
<div="Box1" style="background-color:Transparent;border-color:Transparent;border-style:None;height:436px;"></div>
```

I need to be able to pick this out but the height is different on every page

so all the rest is exactly the same but the height changes

Comment: Try this: `div="Box1" style="background-color:Transparent;border-color:Transparent;border-style:None;height:(.*?)px;`

Comment: What do you need that `regex` for?

Comment: Is that `<div id="Box1"`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you got that line, you can use the following regex to get the height.:

```
'<div="Box1" style="background-color:Transparent;border-color:Transparent;border-style:None;height:436px;"></div>'
     .match(/height:([\sa-z0-9]+);/)
```

This will return:

```
["height:436px;", "436px"]
```

This example is in JS, I don't know in what language you want to use the Regex? But in CSS you cant.

Comment: I have a site that has an issue with this height CSS inline on pages, and i am using a piece of software that can find it using reg ex and manipulate it to remove the height, just needed the code to find varying heights.

Answer (score 0):

`[0-9]+` matches an arbitrary number.

However, for the HTML part you should not use a regex at all but a HTML parser - and then only use a regex on the `style` attribute.

Comment: I think he doesn't want to use it in CSS but just tagged the question poorly.

Comment: i do want to use if for CSS, but using a third party IE addon to manipulate it